# Помогите поменять код базовой сложности

Tags: python

Я начинающий программист и то не на python

```py
f = open('words.txt')
for x in range(20000):
    s = decrypt('NHUDMOVUHB', '13')
    for line in f.readlines():
        line = line.strip('\n')
        if s.lower() == line.lower():
            print(line)
```

как сделать так чтобы вместо 13 можно было вставлять x с цикла, 13 принимается только как строка и напрямую x нельзя вставить, пытался написать char = str(x) но не работает

Comment: а вот так `s = decrypt('NHUDMOVUHB', str(x))` уже не работает?

Comment: Покажите саму функцию "decrypt" может там проблемма. Потому что: s = decrypt('NHUDMOVUHB', str(x)) должно работать.

Comment: Понять бы из какого модуля/пакета функция decrypt растет  :)

Comment: Скрипт работает, можешь помочь ускорить его ?)